# await operator can only be used within an async method - but method is asynchron

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I want to use a MessageDialog in VS12. Until now I have used:

```
MessageDialog msgdlg = new MessageDialog("Choose a color", "How To Async #1");
msgdlg.DefaultCommandIndex = 1;
msgdlg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Red", null, Colors.Red));
msgdlg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Green", null, Colors.Green));
msgdlg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Blue", null, Colors.Blue));

IAsyncOperation<IUICommand> asyncOp = msgdlg.ShowAsync();
asyncOp.Completed = OnMessageDialogShowAsyncCompleted;
```

Now I want to eliminate the callbacks and use an anonymous methode with await. For test purpose i used:

```
MessageDialog msgdlg = new MessageDialog("Choose a color", "#3");
msgdlg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Red", null, Colors.Red));
msgdlg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Green", null, Colors.Green));
msgdlg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Blue", null, Colors.Blue));

// Show the MessageDialog
IAsyncOperation<IUICommand> asyncOp = msgdlg.ShowAsync();
IUICommand command = await asyncOp;
```

Problem is, await produces an error, even if ShowAsync() is obviously asynchron. "The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'."

Whats the problem here?

---

Ok, thanks to your comments I now doing this:

```
Loaded += async (sender, args) =>
        {
            #region Using await (from C# 5.0 on)
            MessageDialog msgdlg = new MessageDialog("Choose a color", "#3");
            msgdlg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Red", null, Colors.Red));
            msgdlg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Green", null, Colors.Green));
            msgdlg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Blue", null, Colors.Blue));

            // Show the MessageDialog
            IAsyncOperation<IUICommand> asyncOp = msgdlg.ShowAsync();
            IUICommand command = await asyncOp;

            #endregion
        };
```

Now it works - thanks a lot!

Comment: Please show your method declaration. Presumably it doesn't have the `async` modifier. Why not?

Comment: Once you go async, pretty much your entire callstack should also be marked async. Async all the way down.

Comment: "even if ShowAsync() is obviously asynchron" - doesn't matter. It's complaining about the method you're currently writing, not any methods that you're calling.

Comment: But the method which uses the source from above is a constructor (page).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But the method which uses the source from above is a constructor (page).

You cannot have asynchronous constructors. Move the async work out of the constructor. Maybe move it into a `Load`-like event. I don't know what GUI framework you're using but they always have a `Load` event.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I moved the code into an anonymous methode for loaded. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You should make your method `async`.You can't use `await` inside of a `non-async` function.

Comment: But the method which uses the source from above is a constructor (page).

Answer (score 0):

The function which calls those codes should be async as well. See details in this MS official sample bellow. Attention that the return of ForgotPassword is async Task< ActionResult > instead of ActionResult.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
        if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
        {
        // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
        return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
    }

    var code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", 
    new { UserId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", 
    "Please reset your password by clicking here: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");        
    return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
}

// If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
return View(model);
}
```